# Why does our calendar look different?

Tags: 2013, calendar

I'm dealing with a new SharePoint 2013 install, and for some reason the calendar looks very different from our development site.

[image]

Comment: did you / somebody change the layout in designer?

Comment: It is a copy of what is on the development site. But on the development site it looks like out of the box SharePoint.

Comment: After further investigation it seems to be just affecting my IE. I don't know why though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the site to your intranet or trusted site zone. I can't recall what was being blocked / altered, but I believe that will resolve it.